# How do I know which files were corrupted/checked by chkdsk?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, file-corruption, check-disk

One of my drives disappeared and was checked when I restarted Windows 7 64.

Previously this has happened and I found that some of my MP3's and other files had been badly repaired with wrong and missing segments.

Is there a way to check which files had bugs and were repaired by check-disk so that I can see if I have errors?

Answer (score 4):

**In order to view the results of the chkdsk scan that already ran, do the following:**

1. Open **Control Panel**
2. Go to **Administrative Tools**
3. Select **Event Viewer**
4. Expand folder/icon that says **Windows Logs**
5. Select **Application** log, right click it, and select **Find**
6. Type `wininit` to search for the chkdsk scan you just ran. Click **Find Next**.
7. Click on the `wininit` event in the right window pane that was found in the search.
8. In the bottom window pane you will find the results of the chkdsk scan. Scroll down to see the results of the entire chkdsk session so you can see which files were damaged, repaired, etc

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if there's an "overall listing" for the files, but you can try and run it differently for certain file/s

> chkdsk [volume[[path]filename]]] [/F] [/V] [/R] [/X] [/I] [/C] [/L[:size]]

where as the path/filename is for FAT/FAT32 only and it specifies files to check for fragmentation. rest specs seen below:

```
/F Fixes errors on the disk.  
/V On FAT/FAT32, this displays the full path and name of every file on the disk. On NTFS, this displays cleanup messages, if any.  
/R Locates bad sectors and recovers readable information (implies /F). 
/L:size NTFS only. Changes the log file size. 
/X Forces the volume to dismount first if necessary (implies /F). 
/I NTFS only. Performs a minimum check of index entries. 
/C NTFS only. Skips checking of cycles within the folder structure.
```